# maven-ear-plugin project property lookup fails

Tags: java, maven, maven-ear-plugin

I have created simple ear project with filters. I want to use different settings for each environment, those settings should be passed to generated **`application.xml`** file in the form of env-entries. The generation of ear package is done with [maven-ear-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/) as shown below:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <generateApplicationXml>true</generateApplicationXml>
                <version>6</version>
                <envEntries>
                    <env-entry>
                        <env-entry-name>customProperty</env-entry-name>
                        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
                        <env-entry-value>${custom.property}</env-entry-value>
                    </env-entry>
                </envEntries>
                <applicationName>${custom.property}</applicationName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

To do that I had to use another plugin [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/). It successfully reads properties from file and sets them as maven project properties, so I can insert them in pom.xml file using **`${}`**. It works for most of the pom.xml elements (i.e. **`<applicationName>`**, unfortunately it is not successfully looked up when I place it inside **`env-entry`** element, where I need it. Below is generated **`application.xml`**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_6.xsd" version="6">
    <application-name>default property</application-name>
    <display-name>test</display-name>
    <env-entry>
        <env-entry-name>customProperty</env-entry-name>
        <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
        <env-entry-value>${custom.property}</env-entry-value>
    </env-entry>
</application>
```

It's probably a bug which should be issued at [Maven Ear Plugin](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MEAR), but I don't have an account there. I'm also attaching archived maven project, if somebody would like to check that himself: [test.zip](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30954239/test.zip).

#### Edit

I've managed to overcome this problem using **`maven-resource-plugin`** and filter **`application.xml`** file after it's created as user **@skegg99** proposed. Since I cannot replace this file I had to copy it to META-INF directory. I does not look pretty, I know, but it solves the case for now. Here is additional markup for **`maven-resource-plugin`**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/META-INF</outputDirectory>
                <filters>
                    <filter>src/main/filters/${env}.properties</filter>
                </filters>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

and also here:

```
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/target</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>application.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
```

Whole project configuration can be downloaded from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30954239/test_v1.zip).

Comment: You may want to try maven-resources-plugin to filter application.xml after it is created

Comment: To my knowledge `maven_resources-plugin` works fine for copying files, but not for replacing them. Nonetheless I tried to do that - creating new file works, but when I provide the same directory it erases the file!

Comment: Maven-resources-plugin is intended to do two things. First copying files from one location to an other and filtering those files during the copying. Show your examples.

Comment: @khmarbaise I have prepared a sample configuration where I intend to filter the file and then replace it in the same path. It generates empty file as stated earlier. The only difference between the solution I provided in the question is in the **`<outputDirectory>`** element value. Here is the sample project [testWrong](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30954239/testWrong.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current setup you have this may well be impossible.

I just took a brief look into [the code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/maven/plugins/tags/maven-ear-plugin-2.9/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugin/ear/GenerateApplicationXmlMojo.java?view=markup) where it states that the env entries are load through the [PlexusConfiguration](http://plexus.codehaus.org/plexus-containers/plexus-container-default/apidocs/org/codehaus/plexus/configuration/PlexusConfiguration.html#addChild%28java.lang.String%29).

Without diving too deep into that code as well, I can't see that this part handles the entries any more special than "read XML, put into List".

Comment: So as you say the maven project properties aren't resolved due to way the env-entries are read. I'm not sure now if it is a bug or it is working as expected.

Comment: @TrueCurry Its not a bug but more a missing feature. I suggest you ask on the mailing list for this plugin. In doubt file a bug report, this is close enough for a bug either way. (as one would expect this to work as you did)